# IS NULL clause not supported by Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, cmis

I'm trying to execute this request: `SELECT * FROM cmis:document WHERE descriptionHPN2 IS NULL` but I have this error:

> CMIS Exception: invalidArgument One or more of the input parameters to
>   the service method is missing or invalid.

After investigation, it is caused by the WHERE clause, I could type `SELECT * FROM cmis:document WHERE 1 = 1`, but it won't work either (same error).

Comment: Your second query is not a valid CMIS query and must fail. All WHERE conditions in CMIS QL must contain a property query name. Try something simple like: SELECT * FROM cmis:document WHERE cmis:name='test.txt'

Comment: Thanks @FlorianMüller indeed, the second query doesn't work on Alfresco either. But the first query should work though. This property is queryable. Is there anything else to do to be able to request on a new property?

Comment: Although, `SELECT * FROM cmis:document WHERE cmis:name IS NULL` does not work with the same error message

Comment: I **guess** SharePoint does not allow null strings and therefore refuses all `IS NULL` queries. At least `cmis:name` cannot be null.

Comment: I see... Thanks again, i'm trying to find a way to work around the problem, using IN keyword for example, but it does not seem to be supported either...